# NetBeans 12.5 SVN CLI Not Work in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: svn, netbeans, java-8

I can svn to the server with command line, but not in NetBeans 12.5.

My company's svn server is very old: 1.1.4 (2005)

The environment of my computer:
Ubuntu 22.04
svn version 1.14.1 (r1886195)
NetBeans 12.5
specify java version in **netbeans.conf**:

```bash
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202"
```

**Prefered Client**: `CLI`
**Manage Connection Settings...**: Specify Client Certificate File With the pem file from server

I can connect to svn server by following setting:

#### .bashrc

```bash
export OPENSSL_CONF="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/openssl@1.1/openssl.cnf"
```

#### /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/openssl@1.1/openssl.cnf

```bash
// add this line at beginning
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

```bash
// add these lines at the end of file
[ default_conf ]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = ssl_default_sect

[ssl_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
MinProtocol = TLSv1  
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0
```

NetBeans output following error message in **~/.netbeans/12.5/var/log/message.log**

```java
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.subversion]: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn server url'
svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication
org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn server url'
svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.cli.CommandlineClient.checkErrors(CommandlineClient.java:947)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.cli.CommandlineClient.exec(CommandlineClient.java:925)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.cli.CommandlineClient.update(CommandlineClient.java:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientInvocationHandler.handle(SvnClientInvocationHandler.java:436)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(SvnClientInvocationHandler.java:381)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientInvocationHandler$2.run(SvnClientInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.DefaultMutexImplementation.writeAccess(DefaultMutexImplementation.java:229)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:280)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientInvocationHandler.invoke(SvnClientInvocationHandler.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction.updateRoots(UpdateAction.java:286)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction.access$400(UpdateAction.java:68)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction$4.call(UpdateAction.java:227)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction$4.call(UpdateAction.java:224)
    at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.indexingbridge.Bridge$1.call(Bridge.java:41)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.indexing.IndexingManager.runProtected(IndexingManager.java:361)
    at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.indexingbridge.Bridge.runWithoutIndexing(Bridge.java:36)
    at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.util.IndexingBridge.runWithoutIndexing(IndexingBridge.java:116)
    at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.util.IndexingBridge.runWithoutIndexing(IndexingBridge.java:79)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.util.SvnUtils.runWithoutIndexing(SvnUtils.java:1822)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction.update(UpdateAction.java:224)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction.update(UpdateAction.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction.access$000(UpdateAction.java:68)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.update.UpdateAction$2.perform(UpdateAction.java:133)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnProgressSupport.performIntern(SvnProgressSupport.java:86)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnProgressSupport.run(SvnProgressSupport.java:79)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```